# Euler-Poincaré characteristic as a function from a Hilbert scheme of surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $H$ be an irreducible component of a Hilbert scheme of surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$
whose general point corresponds to a smooth irreducible surface.

Consider the function $\chi:U\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined over the subset $U\subseteq H$ parametrizing smooth irreducible surfaces 
which sends a surface $S$ to its topological Euler-Poincaré characteristic $\chi(S)$.

What property does the function $\chi$ have? For example, is it constant?

Comment: Because $H$ is irreducible and $U$ is open, $U$ is connected, so yes, $\chi$ is constant. This has nothing to do with irreducibility or two-dimensionality of the surfaces - it's a general topological fact about smooth proper maps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you give me a reference for the fact that $\chi$ is a smooth proper map?

Comment: If you're fine reducing to the analytic setting, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_lemma